# Replacing values of a factor variable in a column of a data frame with an existing value of that column

Tags: r

This is my dataset:

```
codes<-c("a1", "b1", "c1", "a2", "b2", "c2", "a3", "b3", "c3")
dt= data.frame(codes)
```

Now I want to replace “a1”,“a2” and “a3” with another existing value say “c3”.
As new to R, I know to replace a single value in a column, as in this case, my code would be:

```
dt$codes[dt$codes== “a1”] <- c3
```

But since I need to replace more than one value here, I am thinking to solve it like this using the OR logic where codes = a1 or codes = a2 or codes = a3

```
dt$codes[dt$codes== “a1” || “a2” || “a3”] <- “c3”
```

Obviously my codes throw some syntax error here. I am thinking that using OR approach might not be correct here.So are there any easy ways to replace the values of a column with an already existing value in that column? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can use `%in%`

```
 dt$codes[dt$codes %in% c('a1', 'a2', 'a3')] <- 'c3'
```

As it is `factor` class, more efficient approach would be to assign using `levels`

```
levels(dt$codes)[levels(dt$codes) %in% c('a1', 'a2', 'a3')] <- 'c3'
```